# AWS Cognito: user pool delete protection?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito

Is there a way to prevent a cloud formation update from deleting or recreating a Cognito user pool resource? I'd like to remove the possibility of this from ever happening. Is there a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. Use DeletionPolicy. Works for any Cloud Formation resource:

```
MyPool:
  Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPool
  DeletionPolicy: Retain
```

Comment: Amazon Cognito now provides user pool deletion protection
 : https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/10/amazon-cognito-console-user-pool-deletion-protection/